# How can I notify a dependent / delegated / calculated property of an update?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

The BountyHunter can either accept jobs to hunt Prey via the JobLine, or choose their own Prey as long as they let the JobLine know. As well as this, the BountyHunter could change JobLines, which would change the active Prey that they are hunting.

How can I make sure that whenever the JobLine Prey changes from it's side, that the BountyHunter is aware of the change of target?

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel;

namespace TestBindings
{

    public class Prey
    {
        public Prey()
        {
        }
    }

    //Prey Provider
    public class JobLine : NotificationObject
    {
        public JobLine(Prey prey)
        {
            this.Prey = prey;
        }

        private Prey _prey;

        public Prey Prey
        {
            get { return _prey; }
            set
            {
                if (_prey != value)
                {
                    _prey = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Prey));
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public class BountyHunter : NotificationObject
    {
        public BountyHunter(JobLine jobLine)
        {
            JobLine = jobLine;
        }

        public Prey Prey
        {
            get { return JobLine.Prey; }
            private set
            {
                if (JobLine.Prey != value)
                {
                    JobLine.Prey = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Prey));
                }
            }
        }

        private JobLine _jobLine;

        public JobLine JobLine
        {
            get { return _jobLine; }
            private set
            {
                if (_jobLine != value)
                {
                    _jobLine = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(JobLine));
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Prey));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it currently not work? Some error or example where it fails? Your `public Prey Prey` in the `BountyHunter` class should fire the "RaisePropertyChanged" when JobLine's Prey changes since you're listening for that exact change.

Comment: BountyHunter will fire a RaisePropertyChanged event when the _JobLine_ changes, but I can't find a neat or tidy way of notifying users of BountyHunter that the Prey has changed when JobLine.Prey changes externally of BountyHunter.

Comment: So you mean the `public Prey Prey { get { return JobLine.Prey; } ... RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Prey));` of the `BountyHunter` class does not fire in your described case?